# Is this ternary operator or list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, operator-keyword, ternary

```
h=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
g=["even" if i%2==0 else "odd" for i in h]
print(g)
```

right now i'm learning about list comprehension and ternary operator. list comprehension is used to append items to newlist. but this is also appending items to new list. So above program is ternary operator or list comprehension?

Comment: Short answer: Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

It is both.  Given the expression `["even" if i%2==0 else "odd" for i in h]` we have a ternary expression:

```py
"even" if i % 2 == 0 else "odd"
```

which is *embedded* inside of a larger list comprehension expression:

```py
[ANY_EXPRESSION_AT_ALL for i in h]
```

Expressions can be composed together.  The simplest example is `1 + 1` is an expression, which can be *composed* with the expression `* 2` to produce the expression `1 + 1 * 2`.

Note that I ignored the `g =` part of your second line because assignment is a *statement* in Python, not an expression and does not return a value.  So you can't compose assignments in the same way you compose expressions.

Comment: Also note that Python recently introduced an assignment expression `:=`, so the water is still _more_ muddied in the case of assignment.